# Radio button siempre tildado pero que no sea visible en codigo

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

El día de hoy tengo un problema con un tema que tengo que solucionar en mi código

El problema es el siguiente: tengo un radio button el cual siempre tiene que estar tildado pero no tiene que ser visible y tampoco tiene que ser visto a nivel código.

Lo que tengo es lo siguiente:

```
<?php if ($mi == '1' || $mi != "1"): ?>
   <tr style="visibility: hidden">
      <td><label>Graba nota: </label></td>
      <td>No<input checked="checked" name="carta[grabaCarta]" type="radio" value="N" class="checkImporte">
      <td>
   </tr>
<?php endif; ?>
```

El tema es que es editable si un tercero revisa el código, lo que necesito es que no sea visible a nivel código. ni en vista.

No se me está ocurriendo nada, por eso estoy acudiendo a ustedes.

Comment: Ese if no será siempre true?

Comment: Si el if es true. pero a nivel backend me lo envia como NO! por ende el radio button siempre tiene que estar tildado en no

Comment: Pero si cualquier valor que envíes será igual o distinto de "1"...

Comment: Por cierto, en qué casos necesitas que se muestre? Siempre?

Comment: No se tiene que ver en ningun caso, claro el valor que se envie desde el radio button sera no o si, siempre se tiene que enviar no. PERO NO TIENE QUE SER VISIBLE A NIVEL CODIGO HTML, a no ser que lo puedo hacer a nivel backkend con php.

Comment: "radio button siempre tildado pero que no sea visible en el código html"... llámame loco pero eso suena exactamente igual a una constante booleana

Comment: Te preguntaba si siempre tiene que estar porque en ese caso simplemente defines la constante en el script que recibe los datos del formulario

Comment: No hay forma de que el código no sea visible/editable, la alternativa es que el valor lo hardcodees y en lugar del código del radiobutton pongas una imágen del radiobutton seleccionado.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes probar agregando un div y a este aplicandole display:none

```
<?php
if ($mi == '1' || $mi != "1") : ?>
<div style="display:none">
    <tr >
        <td><label>Graba nota: </label></td>
        <td>No<input checked="checked" name="carta[grabaCarta]" type="radio" value="N" class="checkImporte">
        <td>
    </tr>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Santiago no me serviria, ya que seria visible a nivel codigo html